# Add model a the begin of a Backbone collection when using create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to use `create` and at the new model at the beginn of the collection instead of appending it at the end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backbone delegates the insertion to [`Collection.add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) which means you can pass an *at* option to specify the position:

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/echo/json/'
})
var c= new C([
    {name: 1},
    {name: 2},
    {name: 3}
]);

c.create({name: 4}, {at: 0});
console.log(c.pluck('name'));
```

will yield `[4,1,2,3]`

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/p6fNR/

Answer (score 3):

Note: these days you can use [unshift](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-unshift)

```
var ships = new Backbone.Collection;

ships.unshift([
  {name: "Flying Dutchman"},
  {name: "Black Pearl"}
]);
```

Comment: For added clarity, you can use the Backbone 'unshift' function that rekarnar links too, not the native JavaScript array 'unshift' on the Backbone Collection's 'models' property. 

Before reading this answer I previously tried adding the model to the 'models' array using the native JavasScript unshift function and this does not properly register the model with the Collection.